# What is Community Wiki?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

The FAQ for Stack Overflow mentions Community Wiki two or three times without ever defining the term.

There is plenty of information (oh, my aching head) over here at Meta, as I discovered after posting this.

A pointer to it, or just a concise definition, would be helpful as part of the content reached from the FAQ link at the top of Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is part of the FAQ, too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

The link to the [detailed FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=faq&sort=votes) already exists:

[alt text http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/4505/detailedfaq.png](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/4505/detailedfaq.png)